# SharpSVN Working Copy Locked (cleanup doesn't clean)

Tags: sharpsvn

I am using SharpSVN as part of a server-pull solution.  The program reads a revision from a config file, if it doesn't match, it updates to the specified revision.

This seems to be working correctly on my developer machine, but when I push it up to my server, I get a "Working copy XXXXXXX' locked" error." TortoiseSVN can update the w.c. properly.  TortoiseSVN for cleanup works fine too.

I tried to catch the 'locked' error and call 'unlock', but that function indicates that the w.c. isn't locked.  I've also attempted to catch the error and call 'cleanup' from SharpSVN, but that results in an error indicating "attempt to write a readonly database."

I've deleted the SVN working copy and re-checked out.  I've moved it to new locations.  I've changed the permissions.  I've changed the read-only flag.  Nothing has worked.

This seems to be similar to some other errors, but most of those were solved by a 'cleanup' or deletion.

Any suggestions, ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This may have been an issue with TortoiseSVN, or a combination between TortoiseSVN and SharpSVN.  After coding a checkout into my program, which would first checkout the code before any subsequent updates, it seems be be working properly.

Thanks.